# Lucene.net PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper - Controlling Index Version

Tags: lucene.net

We use a factory to build lucene analyzers in a consistent fashion, and we've sort of reached a tipping point.

Analyzer construction looked like this:

```
    public Analyzer Construct(string[] keywordFields)
    {
        var analyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));

        var keywordAnalyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();

        foreach (var field in keywordFields)
        {
            analyzer.AddAnalyzer(field, keywordAnalyzer);
        }
        return analyzer;
    }
```

We've reached a point where it makes more sense to default to the keyword analyzer, and specify fields we want to use a tokenizing analyzer on, eg:

```
    public Analyzer Construct(string[] nonKeywordFields)
    {
        var analyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(new KeywordAnalyzer());

        var fullTextAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);

        foreach (var field in nonKeywordFields)
        {
            analyzer.AddAnalyzer(field, fullTextAnalyzer);
        }
        return analyzer;
    }
```

I noticed when looking at the index with Luke that this approach changes the index version from lucene 3 to lucene 2.9, which may or may not be an issue (Probably not).

It still has me curious though - as far as I know the only way to control the index version is through the analyzer passed to your index writer - is there a better way?  If not, I'm wondering if there is any way to control the version if my default analyzer is a KeywordAnalyzer?